# How to access each element of each row when inputting line by line in python

Tags: python

I have a tab-delimited csv file.
My csv file:

```
    0.227996254681648   0.337028824833703   0.238163571416268   0.183009231781289   0.085746697332588   0.13412895376826
    0.247891283973758   0.335555555555556   0.272129379268419   0.187328622765857   0.085921240923626   0.128372465534807
    0.264761012183693   0.337777777777778   0.245917821271498   0.183211905363232   0.080493183753814   0.122786059549795
    0.30506091846298    0.337777777777778   0.204265153911403   0.208453197418743   0.0715575291087 0.083682658454807
    0.222748815165877   0.337028824833703   0.209714942778068   0.084252659537679   0.142013573559938   0.234672985858848
```

Now I would like to input each line from the csv file, do something with each element of each row and then do the same thing for the next line and so on.

My code:

```
lines = []
    with open("/path/testfile.csv") as f:
        csvReader = csv.reader( f, delimiter="\t" )
        for row in csvReader:
            x=row[0] #access first floating number of each line from csv
            y=row[1] #access second floating number of each line from csv
            z=row[2] #access third floating number of each line from csv
            r=row[3] #access fourth floating number of each line from csv
            s=row[4] #access fifth floating number of each line from csv
            t=row[5] #access six floating number of each line from csv
            #do something else with each element
```

Here I only included `print(row[0])` into the `for` loop:

```
lines = []
with open("/path/testfile.csv") as f:
    csvReader = csv.reader( f, delimiter="\t" )
    for row in csvReader:
        print(row[0])
```

But when already trying only `print(row[0])`, it already prints out all values from the csv file. How can I access each element from each row in python?

Comment: Normally you'd set the delimiter as `delimiter="\t"` for tab-separated files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you are familiar with the [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) library. You could use pandas which will simplify things a lot.

##### Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./data/data.csv', delimiter='\t', header=None)
print(df)
```

##### Output

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.227996  0.337029  0.238164  0.183009  0.085747  0.134129
1  0.247891  0.335556  0.272129  0.187329  0.085921  0.128372
2  0.264761  0.337778  0.245918  0.183212  0.080493  0.122786
3  0.305061  0.337778  0.204265  0.208453  0.071558  0.083683
4  0.222749  0.337029  0.209715  0.084253  0.142014  0.234673
```

You can then you can any operation you want on any column. Example :

```
df[0] = df[0]*10    # Multiply all numbers in the 0th column by 10
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another loop:

```
lines = []
with open("/path/testfile.csv") as f:
csvReader = csv.reader( f, delimiter=" " )
for row in csvReader:
    for element in row:
        do_something_with(element)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but then it only prints `0`'s, when using `print(element[0])`. So it only accesses the `0`'s of each first element in each row. How can I access the whole number?

Comment: As I already noted, you guys are using the wrong delimiter. `" " != "\t"`. You need `"\t"`.

Comment: It makes no difference. I used `"\t"` now but it gives the same result...

Comment: @Luker354 are you sure the file you're reading is in fact tab-separated?

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at the pandas library, it's a good starting point.

[User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html). It will allow you to easy handle and process your data easier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).